# Flutter Drop DownMenuItem Widget

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout

I want to develop a drop down button in Flutter. But I am getting Following Error.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building DefaultTextStyle(debugLabel: (englishLike body1 2014).merge(whiteMountainView body1), inherit: false, color: Color(0xffffffff), family: Roboto, size: 14.0, weight: 400, baseline: alphabetic, decoration: TextDecoration.none, softWrap: wrapping at box width, overflow: clip):

The getter 'value' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: value

Here is my code.

```
String Selected_Category;
List<String>Categories=["C++","Java","Flutter","Kotlin","PHP","C#"];    
DropdownButton<String>(
        focusColor: Colors.redAccent,
        items: Categories.map(
            (String dropdownStringItem) {
             DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                   value: dropdownStringItem,
                   child:
                   Text(dropdownStringItem),
                   );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (value) {
                   setState(() {
                          this.Selected_Category = value;
                     });
               },
       value: Selected_Category,
    ),
```

Please Help me that how can i solve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are not returning DropDownButton.

You are just missing return keyword.

```
return DropdownMenuItem<String>( // return keyword added
```

Comment: i'm Using in this in a Column. That's why i'm not returning it.

Comment: I am taking about returning DropdownMenuItem not whole dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because your `Selected_Category` variable is not initialized.

Give it a default value and you will good :)

Comment: i'm getting same Problem. The Same Code is working in an other page while causing error in that page

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you build a dropdown button:

```
String dropdownValue = 'One';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DropdownButton<String>(
    value: dropdownValue,
    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
    iconSize: 24,
    elevation: 16,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.deepPurple
    ),
    underline: Container(
      height: 2,
      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
    ),
    onChanged: (String newValue) {
      setState(() {
        dropdownValue = newValue;
      });
    },
    items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
      .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      })
      .toList(),
  );
}
```

Comment: Done with this Code. Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 0):

You can set value: 'c++' or initialise selected_category to either one option like

```
         Selected_category = 'c++'
```

Comment: i'm getting same Problem. The Same Code is working in an other page while causing error in that page

Comment: It's not about where you use,  check in the accept answer, he also returns.